# NextJS react hook - Pass async state to child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am still new to react hook, and I do not get how to pass an async state parent to child ?

```
    const [isMob, setIsMob] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsMob(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches ? true : false)
    }, [])
    
    ...

    <Child isMob={IsMob} />
```

The problem is that the value is not set when I read it from my child. It keep being `null`.

How to pass to my child a state set after the first load of the component ?

I also tried to set directly useState like so and to use `ref`

`const [isMob,setIsMob] = useState(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches)`

But I got an `Window is not defined` so I've tried to force it to wait like so `isMob != null ? <Child isMob={IsMob} /> :  null`

And on this case it is even more obscure for me I get an error from another component without changes.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
Process.componentDidMount
./sections/Process.js:285
  282 |     window.addEventListener('wheel', (this.getScrollDirection));
  283 |     this.offsetTopFromBottomOfEl = window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector("#process").getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  284 |     this.savedScrollOnMount = window.pageYOffset
> 285 |     this.offsetTop = window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top;
      | ^  286 |    this.countScroll = 1
  287 | }
  288 |
```

So I was hopping maybe to find a solution like async await or something to pass my data into the child. But maybe it is not the right way.

Comment: Why not <Child isMob={isMob} /> ?

Comment: Bad copy and past ;)

Comment: You just made an edit after my comment, lol

Answer (score 4):

Your initial value is `null`, and on the first render it's the value of `isMob` that is passed to the component. After the 1st render, `useEffect()` sets `isMob`, and the component is re-rendered with the new value.

Since you are using SSR (server side rendering) via next.js, you need to wrap calls to `window` with `useEffect()`, because `window` would only be available after the 1st render. In this case block rendering the `Child` until `isMob` is set. For example:

```
const [isMob, setIsMob] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  setIsMob(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches)
}, [])

return isMob === null ? null : <Child isMob={IsMob} />
```

If you are not using SSR, window would be available, and you can skip  `useState` and `useEffect` for a one time value. Use `useMemo` to get the value, and cache it for further use:

```
const isMob = useMemo(() => window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches)
```

Comment: ReferenceError: window is not defined. That's why I set it in useEffect. Any idea ? :/

Comment: I a agree with @Adam - you are asking the wrong question. If you are in a browser environment, and not in a worker, `window` would be always available.

Comment: Sorry still editing my answer to show you all what I tired. I also tired what you just said with the ternary.

Comment: You are using SSR. so the solution is to use `useEffect`. In that case you need to block the 1st render with something like the ternary. `isMob` can also be `false`, so you need to check explicitly for `null`.

Comment: If I block the 1st render with a ternary I got another error on an unchanged component about getBoundingClientRect

Comment: You can block the render inside the `Child` using the same logic. If the property `isMob` is `null` don't render anything.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using SSR (server side rendering) via next.js, so `window` is only available after render is done via `useEffect`. In this case, we've solved the error for `Child`, but your other component also uses `window`. It crashes now, because it was rendered before due to `Child` throwing an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232001/discussion-between-crg-and-ori-drori).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to pass state to child component then

```
const [isMob, setIsMob] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsMob(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches ? true : false)
    }, [])



<Child isMob={isMob} />
```